# How to configure bind9 caching period

Tags: linux, configuration, bind9

I have configured bind9 to act as a caching server and is working properly. However I am trying to configure the retention period for the cache. I couldn't find any information regarding the caching period or how to configure it.

How do I configure the retention period for DNS caching? My purpose is to increase the retention period.

Answer (score 3):

bind9 uses the time-to-live (TTL) values specified as part of each DNS record to determine how long to cache it. That's what's required by the DNS standards. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to override that in bind, and upstream isn't likely to change that [because it's generally a bad idea](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.protocols.dns.bind/43ZNpJUEfyA/2yY9GHH4cuQJ).

One option is to run Debian's version of bind9; they have patched it to add in a `min-cache-ttl` option.

If you're not running Debian, on Serverfault, OmniWired suggests that you can grab the source and [edit the `is_expired` function](https://serverfault.com/a/114010/1006) to change the caching behavior. His example just changes the `return 1` (expired) to `return 0` (not expired); obviously C programming knowledge would be required to implement anything more complicated.

If you have some C knowledge, you could also apply the [Debian min-cache-ttl patch](http://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/users/lamont/bind9.git/commit/?h=patches&id=84fa402750fab5cd887d357501e2896494ac551f).

Another alternative is the [Unbound DNS server](http://unbound.net/) which has a `cache-min-ttl` directive to override too-low TTLs.